# IntelliJ IDEA. Пропадает дерево проекта

Tags: intellij-idea

На 1 изображении то, как изображается дерево проекта при его создании и как хотелось бы мне его видеть. На 2 то, что происходит в силу не ясных мне причин. На диске остаются все файлы проекта. Подскажите, как привести все в исходынй вид.

[image: 1]
<sub>(источник: [userapi.com](https://pp.userapi.com/c837538/v837538795/287a2/mRQ6cgEq-mw.jpg))</sub>

Comment: в какой момент происходит изменение? у вас два совершенно разных проекта.

Comment: Да, проекты разные. Происходит при перезапуске intellij, но не всегда.

Comment: Обычно помогает меню File - Invalidate caches или File - Repair IDE